# PHP modules on CentOS Server - Which ones do I need?

Tags: php, wordpress, module, webserver, centos

I have just installed all the components of LAMP onto my CentOS Web Server.
Now there are several libraries I can choose from to install:

My Needs: I just want to run a **Webserver** and install **Wordpress** on it.

**My Question: What modules do I need?**

```
[root@***** ~]# yum search php-
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: 
 * extras: 
 * updates: 
============================================== N/S Matched: php- ==============================================
php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath library
php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
php-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
php-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP applications
php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
php-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
php-enchant.x86_64 : Human Language and Character Encoding Support
php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
php-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics library
php-imap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
php-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
php-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need multi-byte string handling
php-mysql.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases
php-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
php-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
php-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
php-pecl-apc.x86_64 : APC caches and optimizes PHP intermediate code
php-pecl-apc-devel.x86_64 : APC developer files (header)
php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 : Extension to work with the Memcached caching daemon
php-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
php-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process interfaces
php-pspell.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using pspell interfaces
php-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode library
php-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed devices
php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP protocol
php-tidy.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides tidy library support
php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC protocol
php-zts.x86_64 : Thread-safe PHP interpreter for use with the Apache HTTP Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not have the complete list, but here would be some suggestions:

- php-mysql
- php-pdo
- php-pear
- php-pecl
- php-xml

If I were you, however, I would install the [PEAR package manager](http://pear.php.net/), and install all your required extensions or modules from that. Seems like that would be easier to manage all your php libraries from a single source, because I would bet that at some point you'll want to use a php library that's not available via your yum repository.

Comment: thank you dsw88. I found on an online tutorial that I need only the following php module to be able to get Wordpress working: php-gd. So I only did yum install php-gd and it works fine now. Thanks for the help